# Database design issue - add tasks to users

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a table:

```
USER {UserId, Email ...}
```

This table is in 1:1 relationship with:

```
PROFILES {UserId, FirstName, LastName ...}
```

I have a roles table where user can ask for role **PROFESSOR**.
One professor can give different tasks to some student.
So I have tried:

```
UserProfessors {ProfessorId, StudentId} // both related to profiles table
```

That is how I connect Professor and Student but I added:

```
Tasks{TaskId, Title, Description ...}
```

But don't know how to join this table now?
Any advice on this kind of design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join tasks to users, you want a `ProfessorStudentTask` table with fields of

```
 ProfessorID -- links to Users
 StudentID -- links to Users
 TaskID
```

or you could link tasks to the `UserProfessors` table

```
 UserProfessorID -- links to UserProfessors via the primary key of UserProfessors
 TaskID
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

1)Table one  **Users** Columns with   ( UserID,userNames, dob, .....)

2) Table two **PROFESSOR** with UserID,ProfID, Dept, bla bla
PROFESSOR

3) Table three **Students** with UserID, StudentID, bla bla

4) Table four **Tasks** with columns like (StudentID, ProfID, TaskID, bla bla bla)

Comment: If you do some study on DATABASE NORMALIZATION it will give you better understanding of what you need to do to reduce the data redundancy, reduce storage and atomicity and obviously you understand your business requirements more than anyone else on here, So once you have a better idea of DATA NORMALIZATION you will be able to answer this question better than anyone else :)

Comment: I rekcon before you go ahead with building your databse you give plenty of attention to how to go about your database design, Its better to take time now and do it the right rather then trying to fix it later when you run into problems. Have a look this is a good read http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization